# Datebox breaks into 2 lines JQueryMobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having a JQuery Mobile's Date box in my HTML layout and when I place it with a button or when I place it pararraly with a button in a Grid Layout then the datebox text input breaks to 2 lines height.
[image]

```
 <table>
 <tr>
      <td><div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                <a id="btnPrevDate" data-role="button" href="#"  data-theme="a">PREV</a>
                <a id="btnNextDate" data-role="button" href="#"  data-theme="a">NEXT</a> 
        </div></td>
 <td> <div><input name="difereddelv"  id="datepickerAct" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox"}'></td></div>

 </tr>
 </table>
```

Can someone help  me out thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did some CSS hack and it worked :)

```
<style>
    .ui-input-datebox input
                {
                width: 70%!important;
                }
</style>
```